# how do if and else behave exactly?

Tags: c, if-statement

an example from a book:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                    
#define IN 1                                                                                                        
#define OUT 0                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                    
main()                                                                                                              
{                                                                                                                   
    int c, nl, nw, nc, state;                                                                                       
                                                                                                                    
    state = OUT;                                                                                                    
    nl = nw = nc = 0;                                                                                               
                                                                                                                    
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {                                                                                
        ++nc;                                                                                                       
        if (c == '\n')                                                                                              
            ++nl;                                                                                                   
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')                                                                     
            state = OUT;                                                                                            
        else if (state == OUT) {                                                                                    
            state = IN;                                                                                             
            ++nw;                                                                                                   
        }                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                               
    printf("lines: %d\nwords: %d\ncharacters: %d", nl, nw, nc);                                                     
}
```

suppose the input was `stack overflow`. here is my understanding of how this code will function:

1.`getchar()` will take `s` from the buffer, so `c = 's'`, and add 1 to `nc`.

2.check if `c` is `\n`. if true, add 1 to `nl`.

3.check if `c` is a blank, a newline, or a tab. if true, state is 0.

4.'else if' `state` is 0, `state` is 1 and add 1 to nw.

my question is:
in step 4, why is `else if` necessary? even without `else`, `state` should still be checked if `0`, no? will the rest of the `while` body be skipped if one of the `if` checks are true? how do theses loops behave exactly?

Comment: The code does what it states. If it is what you want it to do or not is anybody's guess.

Comment: The way I read that is if there's a newline then increase the line count. If there's a whitespace character set the state to OUT. If there is not a whitespace character and the previous character was a whitespace character increase the word count and set the state to IN. Makes sense to me.

Comment: Without the `else`, it would be `if ((c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\t') && state == OUT)`. The `else` saves you from having to recheck whether the current character is a whitespace character.

Comment: if you take out the `else` keyword then a space input will set OUT and then immediately set IN and ++nw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you become familiar with debugging procedural code like your C program, then you'll quickly become familiar with how `if` and `else` work.

If you are not going to become familiar with debuggers, then add print statements and execute your code (BTW, what you pasted has annoying trailing whitespace for each line).

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

int main (int argc, char *argv[] ) { // always use proper signatures
    int c, nl, nw, nc, state;

    state = OUT;
    nl = nw = nc = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        ++nc;
        if (c == '\n') {
            ++nl;
            printf("found newline: nc=%d\n", nc);
        }
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') {
            state = OUT;
            printf("found whitespace: nc=%d\n", nc);
        } else if (state == OUT) {
            printf("found non-whitespace: '%c' nc=%d\n", c, nc);
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
        }
    }
    printf("lines: %d\nwords: %d\ncharacters: %d", nl, nw, nc);
}
```

Here's what happens when you execute your code with more instrumentation:

```
$ a.out
stack overflow
found non-whitespace: 's' nc=1
found whitespace: nc=6
found non-whitespace: 'o' nc=7
found newline: nc=15
found whitespace: nc=15
lines: 1
words: 2
characters: 15
```

To answer the question in your 2021-05-24T21:31:32Z comment on this answer, the true block of the `if` that has the `c == '\n'` executes and then the next `if` will execute. That is, if the predicate for the true block evaluates to true. If it does not evaluate the true, then the next `if` statement is the next thing that is executed. The only way the first `if` statement's true block could cause rest of the while loop body to be skipped is if the true block looked like this instead:

```
    if (c == '\n') {
        ++nl;
        printf("found newline: nc=%d\n", nc);
        continue; // jump to the end of the enclosing loop body
    }
```

In my opinion, your code is not properly formatted and that is why you are confused. The second `if` (if not refactored) should look like this:

```
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') {
        // on a whitespace character so we're OUTside a word
        state = OUT;
        printf("found whitespace: nc=%d\n", nc);
    } else {
        // on a non-whitespace character so we're INside a word
        if (state == OUT) {
           printf("found non-whitespace: '%c' nc=%d\n", c, nc);
           state = IN;
           ++nw;
        }
    }
```

If the variable being compared in the `if` is the same variable as the one being compared in the `else if`, then it's ok to format the `else if` in the manner you used.

But they are different variables: one is `c` and the other is `state`, so to make sure you understand the context and keep it in your mind while reading the next `if` predicate, you should indent.

Comment: also, if the first `if` test is true, and `++nl`, does the program continue the rest of the while loop? or does it go back to the beginning of the while loop?